# crispy forms tabs non English

Tags: django, forms

I am relative new to coding. My problem is that although my crispy form works fine,
I want to write the tabs and label forms in Greek. When I do that inside the Tab crispy forms can't see to recognize the Greek alphabet. On tabs just changes the tab without displaying the content. On label (input) just hide the input, rendering only the English characters.

class ExampleForm(ModelForm):

```
helper = FormHelper()
helper.form_method = 'POST'
helper.layout = Layout(
    TabHolder(

        Tab('A',
            'name', #in Greek 'ονομα' doesn't being rendered#
            'surname',
            'birthdate',
            'school_id'),

        Tab('B',
            'fathers_name',
            'fathers_surname',
            'fathers_origin'),

    ),
)

helper.layout.append(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))

class Meta:
    model = Example
    fields = ['name' , 'surname' , 'birthdate', 'school_id' , 'fathers_name', 'fathers_surname', 'fathers_origin']
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zgcy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaXWm.png)

Comment: Post the code for your model.